# joomla, separated read more and intro text

Tags: joomla

how separated read more and intro text?

Now i get only one string(text redactor: tinymce), and wish "read more" insert in one table, intro text other.
How make that?

Answer (score 1):

Joomla stores these two text parts in one table column - this is by design.